# How to get value from a serializable object

Tags: android, serialization, intentservice

I pass an object from type `serializable` via a `BroadcastReceiver` from an `IntentService` to a `BroadcastReceiver`. 
This code is assigned to the `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: Received Broadcast: " + intent + " from context: " +  context);

        RetrofitResponseProfile retrofitResponseProfile = intent.getSerializableExtra(NetworkService.NETWORK_RESPONSE_PROFILE);



    }
```

But my problem is, that android studio says, the `retrofitRepsonseProfile` object isn't from type `serializable`.

Can anybody help me, how to receive an `serializable` object from an `IntentService` in a `BroadcastReceiver`?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: add the code that you are passing the serializable too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Class Should Be

```
Class RetrofitResponseProfile implements Serializable{
//Create Variables And Functions
}
```

And During Call

```
RetrofitResponseProfile retrofitResponseProfile = (RetrofitResponseProfile) intent.getSerializableExtra("Key0");
```

hope this may help you

Comment: Happy To Know That. Happy Coding

Comment: One last question: 
Now, I want to insert this object into a room database, that already has been created. Is it possible to do this with a asynctask in the same scope like above?

Comment: yes It Is possible,If The object is an object of Entity Class That is RetrofitResponseProfile.

Comment: Not directly, because I have another class called roomprofile and before the asynctask would be executed, I convert the RetrofitResponseProfile into a room compatible class object.

Comment: If you converted the same you can save the data by roomdb using async task